# Why this <a> margin doesnt move the container div?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yhx7A/) code :

```
.myDiv
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.myLink
{
    background-color: red; 
    margin-top: 20px; 
}

<div class="myDiv">
    <a class="myLink" href="javascript:void(0)">Ciao</a>
</div>
```

if I increase the `margin-top` I'd aspect that the div becomes more hight (and the  go to the bottom of the div), but in fact this doesnt happens! The same with `padding-top` (it go out of the div...). It doesnt listen the container!

Why? And how can I fix this trouble?

**EDIT**

in fact what Id like to do is align an input box and a image, you can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yhx7A/1/) :

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <a style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:5px;" href="#">
        <img alt="Cerca" src="/private_images/home_button_right.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update of the question:

Updated [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhx7A/2/).

CSS:

```
input,
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Or use `vertical-align: top;` to align the tops.

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
.myLink
{
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
div {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yhx7A/1/ : i have to align input box and image (doesnt import if you don't see it.. :))

Comment: @markzzz what if you add *padding-top* only to the div, and not the link?

Comment: Div hans't the padding-top... I'd like to move the image bottom, so it will be aligned...

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block;` or maybe even better: `display: inline-block;`. Block elements can have height. Inline elements not.

You might also consider to give the anchor a larger line-height (e.g. `line-height: 2em;`), but that only works for single-line text.

Answer (score 1):

Do the opposite thing:

```
.myDiv
{
    background-color: blue;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.myLink
{
    background-color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.myDiv
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.myLink
{
    background-color: red;
    display:list-item;
}
```

You can use display:list-item; to solve this problem